# IOErr:204800 requested 103926 written

Tags: python, numpy

I am so many files with npy extension. These files are storing arrays having zeros and ones. After replacing zeros with -1 I again try to save then upto the value of .4f. But I am getting the error.
Can some one please guide me about this error?How I can fix that?

Comment: Hello huda and welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your question is unclear because it doesn't contain any of your code, so we don't know where the problem arises from and we can't debug. Please add your code. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide us with a working example?